# How to ignore content within <sup></sup> tags when using pandas.read_html?

Tags: html, pandas, lxml

How to ignore content within `<sup></sup>` when using `pandas.read_html` method?

An an example the table data `<td>12&nbsp;December 2018<sup>1</sup></td>` gets converted to `12 December 20181`.

How to ignore content from within `<sup>` tags?

Comment: The documentation clearly states: `Expect to do some cleanup after you call this function` . So I would just iron these issues out with some code after having read the data.

Comment: @PankajJoshi Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems. - Jamie Zawinski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with Pandas advice

> Expect to do some cleanup after you call this function.

is that it removes the markup, so the needed information to do a proper cleanup is lost.

The only solution I see is to cleanup the HTML as a preprocessing step. You can use [`lxml.html.clean.Cleaner`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.html.clean.Cleaner-class.html) for that purpose. As a starting point you can try something like:

```py
from lxml.html.clean import Cleaner


def clean_html(raw_html):
    cleaner = Cleaner(remove_tags=["sup"])
    return cleaner.clean_html(raw_html).decode("utf-8")
```

And then use the cleaned HTML in `pd.read_html`. You may have to play around with the other settings of the cleaner to preserve/clean exactly the content you need.